# How to prevent Recycler view item from executing the same task twice

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, multi-touch

I have implemented an Recycler view with its item click inside the Holder class. Each item click opens a new activity. The problem is when user clicks an item twice in a fast tap (very quickly very less span of time), it opens the activity twice.

I can't try below solution:

1. `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` as I am using
   `startActivityForResult()` to call the new activity.
2. `android:launchMode="singleTask"` is also not working.

How can it be stopped from happening? Please suggest.

Below is my adapter class:

```
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

            switch (viewType) {

                case MY_VIEW_TYPE:

                    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.created_by_me_item, parent, false);

                    viewHolder = new ViewHolderCreatedByMe(v1);

                    break;    

            }
            return viewHolder;
        }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       if (holder instanceof ViewHolderCreatedByMe) {
            // The data setting method is inside the Holder class
            ((ViewHolderCreatedByMe) holder).setDataCreatedByMe(mFeedRecordListData.get(position));

        } else {

            ((ViewHolderFooter) holder).setFooterView();
        }
    }
```

And below is my holder class:

```
public class ViewHolderCreatedByMe extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    // ... some class members are declared here


    public ViewHolderCreatedByMe(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        // a few more UI components are initialized here

        rl_reaction_item_main_layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_reaction_item_main_layout);

        rl_reaction_item_main_layout.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.rl_reaction_item_main_layout:

                Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, NewActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_ID, UIModel.getEventID());

                intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_TIME_STAMP, UIModel.getEventLocalTimeStamp());

                intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());

                mFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share the code, where you are starting a new activity along with the adapter code.

Comment: Show us your adapter code.

Comment: @AlokOmkar Please look into the added code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a boolean flag to check weather row item is clicked or not like this.

boolean isItemClicked = false;

```
private void onRecyclerViewItemClick()
{
    if(!isItemClicked)
    {
        isItemClicked = true;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    isItemClicked = false;
}
```

*Note- I used name onRecyclerViewItemClick() for example here, it will be replaced with your listView's onItemClick

Comment: This boolean way will definitely work but I am currenlty looking for some other way to do that. If i don't get some other resolution then I will go your way. Thanks :)

Comment: just add this line when you starting your activity

**intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);**

It will work definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface to intercept click on the view of your recyclerview item.

For example :

```
public interface CustomClickListener {
   void onClick(UIModel uiModel, int position);
}
```

Create a method in your adapter class to set the interface defined :

```
private CustomClickListener mCustomClickListener;
public void setClickListener( CustomClickListener customClickListener ) {
    this.mCustomClickListener = customClickListener;
}
```

Modify your view holder class to this :

```
public class ViewHolderCreatedByMe extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    // ... some class members are declared here
    public ViewHolderCreatedByMe(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // a few more UI components are initialized here
        rl_reaction_item_main_layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_reaction_item_main_layout);
        rl_reaction_item_main_layout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if( position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && mCustomClickListener != null ) {
            mCustomClickListener.onClick(UIModel, position);
        }
   }
```

In your fragment class, you would have your adapter defined, set the click listener here :

```
CustomClickListener customClickListener = new CustomClickListener() {
    @Override
    void onClick(UIModel uiModel, int position) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_ID, uiModel.getEventID());
         intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_TIME_STAMP, uiModel.getEventLocalTimeStamp());
         intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_POSITION, position);
         getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);
         adapter.setCustomClickListener(null); //To prevent the event being triggered twice

    }
}
adapter.setCustomClickListener( customClickListener );
```

In your fragment where you have overriden onActivityResult, do this :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent ) {
     if( requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE ) {
         //Do something with the result 
         adapter.setCustomClickListener(customClickListener); // Make customClickListener a global variable
     }
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you've found a better way to tackle the problem if this doesn't suit your needs. The answer based out of boolean will work, but its a mess to track the boolean when you open and close the app.

Answer (score 0):

Add these flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Your click event should look like this

```
case R.id.rl_reaction_item_main_layout:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, NewActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_ID, UIModel.getEventID());

                    intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_TIME_STAMP, UIModel.getEventLocalTimeStamp());

                    intent.putExtra(NewActivity.KEY_EVENT_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());
                    //add these following line 
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    mFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);

                    break;
```

Comment: @SKP Strange , once I faced the same problem , solved in this way . By the way I have edited my answer  . Nothing specific just add some more additional flag . Have a try and let me know

Comment: You might not be calling **startActivity(intent)** instead of **startActivityForResult()** My problem is that i have to call **startActivityForResult()** .

Comment: Corrected the typo of the above comment -  You might be calling **startActivity(intent)** instead of **startActivityForResult()** My problem is that i have to call **startActivityForResult()** .